# I am trying to reset the value of a cookie as part of an Express middleware function - but am unable to

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on an app (my first using Express). I've written a middleware function to decode the users tokens (access, refresh, expires in etc). If the users access token is expired, I want to resave a cookie. So far, I'm unable to do so.

This is the middleware function. At the moment  I'm trying to reset the cookie after determining `if(newToken)`. I'm also just attempting to set a generic token, but that's also not working.

```
const authenticateUser = (jwtSecret) => async (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    if (!authHeader) {
       return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Authorization header missing' });
    }
    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    try {
        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret);

      if ( isAccessTokenExpired( decodedToken.timestamp, decodedToken.expiresIn, decodedToken.accessToken ) ) {
        const newToken = await refreshAccessToken( decodedToken.refreshToken, decodedToken.userId, jwtSecret );
        const newTimestamp = Date.now();
        if (newToken) {
          res.cookie('hello', 'world', { maxage: 90000000 });
          res.cookie('token', token, { maxage: 90000000 });
          req.userData = {
            accessToken: newToken.accessToken,
            refreshToken: decodedToken.refreshToken,
            expiresIn: decodedToken.expiresIn,
            timestamp: newTimestamp,
            userId: decodedToken.userId,
          };
          next();
        }
      } else {
        req.userData = {
          accessToken: decodedToken.accessToken,
          refreshToken: decodedToken.refreshToken,
          expiresIn: decodedToken.expiresIn,
          timestamp: decodedToken.timestamp,
          userId: decodedToken.userId,
        };

        console.log('userData', req.userData);
        next();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('authenticateUser error', error);
      logger(logLevels.error, 'authenticateUser failed', 'authHelpers.js', error);
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid or expired token' });
    }
};
```

I am otherwise successfully using the middleware function to hit the necessary API endpoints

```
router.post('/create-playlist', authenticateUser(jwtSecret), (req, res) => { 
   // functionality here....   
});
```

I am also using cookieParser in my index file and am also successfully setting the inital state of the cookie.

```
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/', authRouter)
app.use(createPlaylistRouter)
```

If someone could please help me, that would  be amazing. Thanks